# How do I get an object that is inside another with nodejs and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to obtain the information contained in the array named `detalleInsumos` through the `_id` of that object.

I have tried many ways, but I still have not found the solution to my problem, since it always shows me all the objects of that document, which does not work for me.

This is the document from which I need to get that information:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53d"},
    "codigoFinca":"000",
    "nombreFinca":"PROVINCIANA",
    "fechaRegistro":"2020-10-21",
    "semanaRegistro":"43",
    "usuarioRegistro":"cotorreo",
    "trabajadoresFinca":[
        {
            "porcentajeRecargo":0,
            "_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53e"},
            "udpTrabajador":[
                {
                    "unidadesAPagar":null,
                    "valorUnidad":"",
                    "areaLaborada":"2",
                    "semanaNormal":null,
                    "semanaAtrazos":null,
                    "_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53f"},
                    "detalleInsumos":[
                        {"_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540"},
                         "codigoInsumo":"20000001",
                         "descripcionInsumo":"NYLON X 5 KILOS",
                         "cantidadAplicada":"153",
                         "idRDI":"426715",
                         "idDetalleSaldo":"24070"
                        }
                    ],
                    "codigoLabor":"101",
                    "nombreLabor":"AMARRE",
                    "loteLaboro":"1"
                }
            ],
            "codigoTrabajador":"0000",
            "nombresTrabajador":"HUMBERTO  MENA MOSQUERA",
            "horasJornada":"10",
            "horasLaboradas":"10"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt":{"$date":"2020-10-21T14:09:29.876Z"},
    "updatedAt":{"$date":"2020-10-21T15:09:51.657Z"},
    "__v":0
}
```

And this is what I have tried from nodejs:

```
const consultauno = await Modelo.findOne({
                'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': new ObjectId(idInsumo)
            },
            {
                "trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos": 1
            });
            console.log(consultauno);
```

Comment: Hi, That is a whole world nested there :)  by my experience your only option would be mongo aggregation and even doing it with aggregation would be a pain.  and you didn't write your `idInsumo` and also `Modelo ` relates to which of these documents. please if it's possible share your `Modelo` Schema and `idInsumo` to see what we can do. Goodluck

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, I have used aggregate to find the  `Insumo` I need but it keeps giving me the entire object as an answer, what I really need is the `Insumo` I am looking for with its respective _id of the object.
In this case the `Insumo` I need is the one with `_id: "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540"`.

Comment: My question is ... how do I get only one object with the `Insumo` values ​​and not the whole object as a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` your condition
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `trabajadoresFinca` array, second $reduce to iterate loop of `udpTrabajador` array, `$filter` to get matching object from `detalleInsumos` array,
- `$arrayElemAt` will get first object from array when condition match
- `$mergeObjects` will merge initialValue or reduce and matching object

```
const consultauno = await Modelo.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id": ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      detalleInsumos: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$trabajadoresFinca",
          initialValue: {},
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$$this.udpTrabajador",
                  initialValue: {},
                  in: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                          {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$$this.detalleInsumos",
                              cond: {
                                $eq: ["$$this._id", ObjectId(idInsumo)]
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/81q75gea8yS)

---

Second approach, you can use `$unwind`,

- `$match` your conditions
- `$unwind` deconstruct `trabajadoresFinca` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `udpTrabajador` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `detalleInsumos` array
- `$match` your conditions
- `$project` to show required fields

```
const consultauno = await Modelo.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id": ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$trabajadoresFinca" },
  { $unwind: "$trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador" },
  { $unwind: "$trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos" },
  {
    $match: {
      "trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id": ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      trabajadoresFinca: "$trabajadoresFinca._id",
      udpTrabajador: "$trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador._id",
      detalleInsumos: "$trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M0OYIeuoE4v)

Comment: excuse my ignorance but ... how do I get the `_id` of `trabajadoresFinca` and `udpTrabajador` in that result?. I need them to update that object again.

Comment: I think its hard to get in my approach, i have added second way you can check.